# how to create amazon clouddrive credentials

Tags: amazon-clouddrive

I have an amazon cloud drive account and i can upload/download files using the amazon cloud drive web interface.

However I want to integrate this service using the amazon clouddrive api. I tried to register an application to amazon, i created a security profile, I successfully whitelisted the security profile to clouddrive according the documentation but all my rest requests are failing.

Can you point me any step by step valid example about how to integrate the amazon clouddrive api in a third party application ?

Best Regards,
Aurelian

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The security profile was not properly filled out and for this reason all the amazon cloud drive api request failed.

In the security profile I used http protocol instead https for all links. So the following links:

- Allowed Origins
- Allowed Return URLs
- Consent Privacy Notice URL

must be HTTPS, otherwise all the REST queries will fail.